# Filling ListBox with custom control in windows phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am working on windows phone app where I need to get the latest streams from a site. I currently made a custom control that can hold each item from JSON:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TwitchStationApp.StreamItem"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="195" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="195" Width="469">
        <Image Height="156" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="imageChannel" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" />
        <TextBlock Height="84" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="174,48,0,0" Name="textBlockStatus" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="294" />
        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="174,12,0,0" Name="textBlockChanelName" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="294" Foreground="#FFB0CB3E" />
        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="174,138,0,0" Name="textBlockViewers" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="294" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

So I will make a list of items `List<Stream> _stream = new ....`. So this list will be populated by lets say 10 items. For each item I need to make a User control (above) and add it to the ListBox so that users can scroll and select (click/tap) on the item they want to get more information about.

What is the best way to do this? I checked microsoft website and there is something about having `ItemTemplate` in a XAML file in `<Window.Resource>` tag but I dont know where and how to create this file and link it to the listbox I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically done using a data template.

Assuming you have a collection of StreamTypes

```
    public class StreamType
    {
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

You can define a Data template in

1. Application wide – in app.xaml
2. Page Scope – on the page
3. Control container scope – local to the container of the listbox
4. Within the Listbox itself

To define it page wide:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SharedStreamTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" Text="{Binding Title}" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" Text="{Binding Description}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

In your list box, assign the data template to the item template

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lstStreams" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SharedStreamTemplate}" />
```

If there isn't a plausible cause for you to re-use the template, just assign it directly in the listbox

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstStreams">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" Text="{Binding Description}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Update

In your code behind

```
  // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindStreams();
    }

private void BindStreams()
    {
        lstStreams.ItemsSource = new List<StreamType>
            {
                new StreamType { Description = "Description One", Title = "Title One"},
                new StreamType { Description = "Description Two", Title = "Title Two"},
                new StreamType { Description = "Description Three", Title = "Title Three"},
            };
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Would you mind to tell me if I use the last option, how can I bind the List<streams> to the ListBox ?

Comment: I just updated the answer, you need to set the control source, i.e lstStreams.ItemsSource and set it to a valid collection such as an IEnumerable or ObservableCollection

Answer (score 1):

That's right you need to use the [ItemsControl.ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property. Using this property, you can specify a template that will be applied to each item in the list. Here's sample code:

**Model:**

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItemsSource}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```